# How to view swagger after deployment on azure

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-devops, swagger, openapi

I have a Spring Boot project and I use Swagger to document my REST services, in particular the dependency used is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Swagger work fine locally at path http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html, but after deployment on Microsoft Azure I'm not able to view it at https://myapp.net/swagger-ui/index.html (Note: https://myapp.net/v3/api-docs works fine, json info are loaded)

The message shown in the browser is

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. There was an unexpected
> error (type=Not Found, status=404).

How can it be solved?

Comment: does your application have a context path?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Default context path used, so '/'

Answer (score 0):

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

This could be because of the page you are trying to access cannot be found.

- Here, the issue might be related to the mapping of the Swagger UI endpoint. Validate the configuration of your Swagger UI endpoint in your Spring Boot application. Make sure that the endpoint is correctly mapped to the URL.
- Make sure your application is up and running where you have deployed and verify the logs as well.

*I have reproduced your requirement from my end with the same dependency you have mentioned, by taking sample spring boot application with swagger 3 configuration.*

I have deployed the application to Azure and I could access the swagger URL.

Below is the dependency which I have used in my application.

```html
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
<artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
<version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
```

**Output:**
[image]

***Refer to my [code](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/swagger_spring-boot-application) which I have used to implement the above scenario.***

Comment: I did the same configurations as yours but I still don't understand why in Azure I can't see the Swagger.
For example, on localhost work:  http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html,  http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs and http://localhost:8080/api/device, on Azure work https://myapp.net/v3/api-docs, https://myapp.net/api/device but not https://myapp.net/swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: Have you allowed the settings `Websites_port:8080` for your application? If not, please try giving port access and check.